# How to query empty string in postgresql?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I have table, in which a column has empty fields.when i try to run simple query like below it is not
returning the data.

```sql
select * from table1 where "colunm1" = ''
```

But below two queries returns data

1,

```sql
select * from table1 
where  coalesce("colunm1", '') = ''
```

2,

```sql
select * from table1 
where  "colunm1" is null
```

Can someone tell me the reason?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

You have describe the behavior of a column that is `NULL`.  `NULL` is not the same as an empty string.

It fails any equality comparison.  However, you can use `is null` or (less preferentially)  `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only database that treats an empty string like a NULL value, is Oracle.

Logically, for a DBMS, that would be wrong.

Relational DBMSs are all about :

- set theory
- Boolean algebra

A NULL value is a value that *we don't know*. A string literal of `''` is a string whose value we know. It is a string with no characters, with a length of 0. We don't know of a NULL as a string how long it is, how many and, if any, which, characters it contains.

So it is only logical that:

- the comparison  `'' = ''` will evaluate to `TRUE`
- the comparison `NULL = NULL` will evaluate to `FALSE` , as any comparison with a NULL value will evaluate to `FALSE`.

And functions like `COALESCE()` or `NVL()`, `IFNULL()`, `ISNULL()` will return the first parameter if it does not contain a NULL value. That is consistent.

Except in Oracle